# How to mock data in javascript unit testing ?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I m using Jasmine library for unit testing my javascript code. I have tried to find a way to mock data, but I didn't found a good solution. Information on how to mock data and libraries which mock data automatically with an example would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) is a generic, framework-agnostic library that enables you to mock entirely data in the browser (by faking XMLHttpRequest Object). You can use it with jasmine e.g. [this way](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon). What this library does is extending jasmine assertions with native sinon features, such as `called`, `threw`, `returned`, etc. See them all [here](https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon#sinonjs-matchers).

In Sinon, you should take a look at [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#server).

Additionally, here you've got a working example of sinon's fakeServer along with jasmine runner written by the author of Sinon.js: https://gist.github.com/cjohansen/739589 :)

And an in-depth introdution to AJAX/sinon: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/javascript/testing/2-ajax-and-sinon.html